# matplotlib: break axis and scale unevenly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a bar-chart that needs to be broken along the x-axis, and after the break the scale of the x-axis should change.

The following code utilizes the `brokenaxes` package (https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes).

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5)))
df['B'] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(50,90,size=(5)))
df = df.sort_values('A', ascending=True)

bax = brokenaxes(xlims=((0, 11), (50, 90)))
bax.barh(np.arange(0, len(df)), df['A'], height=0.3, hatch='/')
bax.barh(np.arange(0.3, len(df) + 0.3), df['B'], height=0.3, hatch='\\')
bax.set_xlabel('value')
bax.set_ylabel('index')
plt.show()
```

The output is as below:

[image]

Currently the x-axis is scaled evenly. I would like to change the x-axis scale such that 0-10 should occupy more space (left half maybe?), and 50-90 should occupy less space (right half).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
brokenaxes(xlims=((0, 11), (50, 90)), width_ratios=[1,1])
```

for equal distribution of the subplots.

Comment: Nothing changed. It's still the same.

Comment: Oh, so I guess the version of `brokenaxes` that is available through pip is too old to allow for this. You would need to install the current version from git available at https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes

Comment: I installed the current version from git as well. Still getting the same output. The `brokenaxes` version I have is 0.3.9.

Comment: I doubt that. Anyways, current version will work, see [here](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes/pull/25/files).

Comment: Tried again on version 0.5.0 and it worked :)